# How to stop Shared Element Transition when navigating from a Fragment with no shared element?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, shared-element-transition

I have two Fragments, call them FragmentA and FragmentB. I am navigating between them using Navigation component and passing the shared elements as FragmentNavigatorExtras.

```
val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(imageView to "image_big")
findNavController().navigate(
    FragmentADirections.actionAFragmentToBFragment(id),
    extras
)
```

Everything is working fine, but FragmentB is also accessible from FragmentC, from where I don't want any transition. In FragmentB I have sharedElementEnterTransition defined in onCreate, and I assume when coming from FragmentC, the shared element is missing, and it plays a default fade in/fade out animation.

Any ideas on how I could circumvent this behavior?